# Fragments Not Swapping

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I Am trying to make a navigation drawer in which there is a listview for swapping fragments. i dont know where i am going wrong.
Here is my code.
SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
    SharedPreferences prefs =  getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarhome);
    toolbar.setTitle("Home");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout dl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    Navigation_Fragment frag = (Navigation_Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragid);
    frag.setUp(dl, toolbar,prefs.getString("firstName", null),prefs.getString("email", null),prefs.getString("url", null));
    ListView  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawerlist);
    String[] drawerlist={"Home","Search"}; 
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SecondActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, drawerlist);
    lv.setAdapter(adapt);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FragmentManager man = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment frag = null;
        switch(arg2){
        case 0 : 
            frag = new Home();
            man.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, frag).commit();
            break;
        case 1 :
            frag = new Search();
            man.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, frag).commit();
            break;
        }

    }
});
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        finish();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = (Editor) getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.clear().apply();
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

home_activity.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/framelayout" >
    <include 
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbarhome"/>

</FrameLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragid"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    class="com.blog.Navigation_Fragment"
    app:layout="@layout/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Navigation_Fragment

```
public class Navigation_Fragment extends Fragment {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer, container, false);

    return view;
}

void setUp(DrawerLayout dl , Toolbar tl , String name ,String emailid,String url){
    drawer  = dl;
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),dl,tl,R.string.app_name,R.string.hello_world);

    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.emailid);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
    tv.setText(name);
    tv2.setText(emailid);
    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).transform(new RoundedTransformation(200, 4)).resizeDimen(R.dimen.img_width, R.dimen.img_height) 
    .centerCrop().into(iv);

}
}
```

Home.java

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "hey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.home);
        tv.setText("Now You See me!!");
        return view;
}
}
```

drawer.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fffff7" >


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/materialdesign_goals_language" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profilepic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emailid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerlist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why using deprecated `ActionBarActivity`?? switch  to `FragmentActivity`

Comment: Can you please elaborate and explain what is the problem, what is the expected result.

Comment: listview in navigation drawer. when you click on items in listview , fragment should be changed according to it in SecondActivity. @ehh

Comment: Where is your `ListView` in your `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: Well i wanted to make a navigationDrawer and isn't Listview present in Drawerlayout ? @KingfisherPhuoc

Comment: I dont see the `ListView` in your layout. the left `Navigation` in your layout is your `Navigation_Fragment `

Comment: @Mayank You should change your `Navigation_fragment` to `ListView` and your code will work.

Comment: my listview is in fragment present in home_activity.xml , i have updated my question , u can see it . @KingfisherPhuoc

Comment: @Mayank you should move your `ListView` and `setOnItemClick` to your `Navigation_Fragment` in `OnCreateView`

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc code inside my home fragment is running(Like  Toast) but The content of the fragment is not seen in my activity.

Comment: I'd suggest removing Imports since they're completely obsolete and take up way too much space and make me not wanna read the post :/

Comment: @Vucko Done!! Now u can read.

Comment: @Mayank Can you remove your: `app:layout="@layout/drawer"`. I dont know the purpose of this line in your xml `fragment`

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc It attach the layout which i want to show in my Drawer. So i cant remove this.

Comment: @Mayank so why did you put your fragment here? When there's nothing to do with the fragment? You should use 1 of 2:  1. your fragment, 2. your layout. Dont try to use 2 at same time.

Comment: you can even remove your `fragment` xml, and replace it with your `drawer` layout (with line: android:layout_gravity="start")